# Notification center: where did the apps Kerberos and CoinChefs come from?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, notifications, malware, virus

I looked in my Notification Center on macOS and see two apps that I did not install:

[image: Kerberos app]

[image: CoinChefs app]

Where did they come from? Are they spyware? Malware?

How can I get rid of them?

**In response to the suggestions below**, I searched in Finder for system files and found the following for CoinChefs:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you find either by name in Spotlight?

Answer (score 2):

## Kerberos

[Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) is part of macOS and stored at:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/SecurityAgentPlugins/KerberosAgent.bundle
```

The icon you can see in the Notification Center is located within this bundle:

```
KerberosAgent.bundle/Contents/Resources/KerberosApp.icns
```

Answer (score 2):

**CoinChefs**

Treat this as suspicious unless you are into cryptocurrencies.

The icon and name corresponds to the web site [CoinChefs](https://coinchefs.com). This is a cryptocurrency converter.

I am not aware of it being a 3rd-party macOS application. Possibly the web site has been wrapped up as an application.  And possibly it is malware, though I can find no reference to it as such.

I suggest you need to search for it on your Mac.  In Finder you will need to enable search for system files. If searching for system files is new to you, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Great tip, didn't know that one. I updated my post with what I found. What do you think? Malware or a Chrome wrapped app? How do I delete it and all traces?

Comment: Potentially a browser add-on have you checked Chrome to see if there are any add-ons you don't expect

Comment: @Baumr Certainly looks like a Chrome add-on (which I would class as malware if you did not add it). All I can suggest is totally removing Chrome and reinstalling. But, I am not a Chrome user and others can hopefully give you more specific advice.